# Single Nginx Load Balancer for 2 different clusters (web, api)

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, high-availability

I was wondering if it was possible to use a single Nginx server to load balance my web servers and api servers if both are using port 80. In this setup there would be 5 servers, 1 Nginx and 4 Apache servers. I would like the web servers to be balanced when web.example.com is accessed.  Likewise, I would like the api servers to be balanced when api.example.com is accessed.

Is this possible or do I need another nginx server?

Comment: I can handle the redundancy of the nginx servers.  I just don't know how to setup an nginx server to balance my web servers separate from my api servers.  I will be using a vip for the 2 nginx servers to handle the load balancing along with keep alive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two possible approach :

**1. A single VIP for both farms :**

In this case, your VIP will be your `NGinx` server single ip address.

```
http {
  upstream web.example.com {
    least_conn;
    server mywebserver1.loc;
    server mywebserver2.loc;
    server mywebserver3.loc;
  }

  upstream api.example.com {
    least_conn;
    server myapiserver1.loc;
    server myapiserver2.loc;
    server myapiserver3.loc;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name web.example.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://web.example.com
    }

   server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://api.example.com
    }

  }
```

**2. A dedicated VIP for each farms**

In that case you need two IP Address on the `NGinx` host.

Let's say :

- 192.168.1.1 for Web (eth0)
- 192.168.1.2 for Api (eth1)

  ```
  http {
    upstream web.example.com {
    least_conn;
    server mywebserver1.loc;
    server mywebserver2.loc;
    server mywebserver3.loc;
  }

  upstream api.example.com {
    least_conn;
    server myapiserver1.loc;
    server myapiserver2.loc;
    server myapiserver3.loc;
  }

  server {
    listen 192.168.1.1:80;   # <-- vHost listen on IP
    server_name web.example.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://web.example.com
    }

   server {
    listen 192.168.1.2:80;   # <-- vHost listen on IP
    server_name api.example.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass http://api.example.com
    }

  }
  ```

Then you have multiple options to manage load-balancing and failover in `upstream` directive, like :

- `weight`
- `max_fails`
- `fail_timeout`

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpUpstreamModule#upstream

Also, you have multiple load-balancing method :

- `least-connected`
- `Session persistence`

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html